# Android Studio (Web page help) net : ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, android-studio

Im trying to implement my web app / page inside android studio from my local files, ive followed the official documentation and made an webview button in xml, and declared :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in the manifest file. My java activity code is below :

```
package samples.opencv.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.loadUrl("file:///C:/Users/olive/OneDrive/Documents/ComputerScience/Project/Atom/index.html");

    }
}
```

but i get the error on the emulator saying the webpage cannot be loaded as file is not found.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHjlf.png) is my HTML File
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e05v7.png) is JS file

Answer (score 1):

Put your web resources into the assets folder, usually under `<project>/src/main/assets`, because emulator cannot see the file under your computer root `".../C:/Users/olive/OneDrive/Documents/ComputerScience/..."`

then call:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Remember that in Android application, files can be read from 3 types of locations:

- **Internal storage**: Each app has its own, file names are relative to
  this location. URL takes form file:///myFolder/myFile.html
- **External storage**: Needs permission and may not always be available.
  Get the root folder by calling
  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). So, construct the URL
  using: String url = "file:///" +
  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "myFolder/myFile.html"
- **Assets**: Stored in the apk. Read-only access. URL takes form
  file:///android_asset/myFolder/myFile.html (See also Loading an
  Android Resource into a WebView)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you i just did that! And now although its not giving me that error, the web page isnt fully loading - i put all my web page files in the assets folder but certain images and camera feed arent loading etc.

Comment: Probably your html page doesn't have the correct path to find all resources, but it is hard to say without code

Comment: it works fine on other text editors like Atom though just has issues on android studio

Comment: Do you have hardcode path inside your html like "C:/Users/olive/OneDrive..."?

Comment: Nope i dont, i can attach my html file if you would like

Comment: Done, ive uploaded the .js file too